# Proper syntax for deleting records using SQLite3?

Tags: python, variables, sqlite

Im trying to write a delete function using SQlite 3 in python and it won't delete.

```
import sqlite3
        import sys
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Employee.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        delemp=input("Please Type your SSN :"))
        def read_from_db():
                c.execute("DELETE FROM Employee WHERE SSN=?", (delemp,))
                conn.commit()
        read_from_db
        c.close()
```

Comment: `read_from_db` is different from `read_from_db()`.

Comment: When debugging, the first thing you need to do is verify your assumptions. You were assuming that `read_from_db` was being executed when it was not. You can verify your assumptions simply by putting print statements inside of functions to verify they run, and use print statements to very that your variables contain the values you think they do. Once the program is working, you can remove the print statements.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Python3, `input` returns a string. Thus, if the table was created with a row `SSN` as an integer, you want to cast your input result as an integer:

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM Employee WHERE SSN=?", (int(delemp),))
```

Also, you need to actually call `read_from_db`:

```
def read_from_db():
   c.execute("DELETE FROM Employee WHERE SSN=?", (delemp,))
   conn.commit()
read_from_db()
```